# Task-based async calls using ChannelFactory and ChannelFactory caching

Tags: wcf, wcfserviceclient

I'm working on a project that is consuming SOAP services via WCF.  Initially, we used generated service references because it was easy to get started.  This provides `ChannelFactory` caching and task-based async methods out of the box, which is clearly desirable.

We've recently switched to using service interfaces and instantiating our own `ChannelFactory`.   We treat the `ChannelFactory` as a singleton object to cache it.  On caching the `ChannelFactory` -- I've been told that a `ChannelFactory` can go bad if, for example, one of its channels fault.  Is this a real concern?

My second question is in regards to using task-based async calls like the ones generated when using the service reference.  How is this done when using a `ChannelFactory<T>`?  I understand that you can annotate methods on `T` with `[OperationContract(AsyncPattern = true)]`, but these return `IAsyncResult` and not `Task`.

Any help would be appreciated.